# Converting OpenTypeFonts with PostScript outlines to TrueType fonts

Tags: opentype

I'm using Silverlight and need to display some OTF fonts. Now Silverlight supports OTF fonts in version 4 but it does not seem to support OTF fonts with PostScript outlines. I have some OTF fonts with postscript outlines that won't show up. Is there a (free) way of converting between OTF with postscript outlines to TrueType fonts or OTF with TrueType outlines. (Incidentally I've tried TransType but am having no joy with it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe I'm having a senior moment, but this question makes no sense to me.

1. An [OTF Font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) font does not contain "PostScript outlines" or "TrueType outlines". It contains OTF data, period. *Edit: this is only true from the application's point of view. As @mustISignUp points out, internally there are many possibilities.*
2. Silverlight supports OTF and TrueType fonts (among others). Those are two independent formats. It doesn't support PostScript fonts.
3. Thus I assume that your real problem is: you have a PostScript font, and you need to convert it into a format that Silverlight supports.

The first question I have to ask: what font? Did you design it? Are you sure there's no TTF or OTF equivalent available?

There are many, many font conversion utilities available -- is that all you need?

**Edit** Okay, your comment makes it clear that the above assumptions are correct. So the questions following are still the relevant ones: what font is this? Is it an original? And also: is high quality high importance (it usually is)?

**Further Edit**

It turns out that there is a bug in Silverlight which is causing a problem: [Silverlight and OpenType fonts with Postscript outlines - rendering problem](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/184153/419193.aspx). So we're both right: an application that supports OTF correctly transparently supports OTF-with-Postcript-Inside, but Silverlight isn't supporting it correctly so all bets are off. Alas.

Comment: I'm working on the basis that Silverlight fails to display my fonts and that when you double click on the fonts in Win7, it describes them as having postscript outlines. I'm sure I read somewhere that Silverlight does not support fonts with postscript outlines, though perhaps I, too , am having a senior moment.

Comment: No, opentype fonts can contain true-type outlines, postscript outlines or even no outlines (bitmaps). There is no such thing as an opentype outline.

Comment: @mustISignUp: +1 thanks for the link, I've revised my answer. And since this discussion began, more information has become available (see the link posted above).

Answer (score 12):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) should be capable.

- open the original OTF in FontForge
- then choose *File > Generate Fonts*
- and choose *TrueType* (*TTF*) as the export type

Comment: This worked for me.  I opened the original OTF in FontForge and then chose File > Generate Fonts and chose TTF as the export type.  For what it's worth I was [encoding a font](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm) for the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) library to embed in PDF's generated by a PHP script.